# ERM for quadratic loss with respect to activation layer

Tags: convex-optimization, machine-learning

So I have to find the hypothesis the ERM algorithm will return to the following quadratic loss:
$l=(\frac{1}{1+e^{-wx}}-y)^2=(\sigma(wx)-y)^2$

I have separable set $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$ where $i=\{1,...,n\}$.
My assumption is that the ERM will return the following hypothesis: 
$$
h(x_i)=
\begin{cases}
1 & wx_i\geq 0\\
0 & wx_i < 0\\
\end{cases}
$$
My reasoning is that the minimal value of a quadratic function is $0$, and in order to achieve $0$ the sigmoid function $\sigma(wx)$ has to return a similar value to $y_i$.

$\sigma(wx)$ is relatively close to 1 when $wx \gg 0$ and $0$ when $wx \ll 0$ and sort of odd around $0$ (with a bias of 0.5). 
So that's why I gave that hypothesis.

Is my reasoning fine?

Comment: By ERM, do you mean empirical risk minimisation? As in, you have loss function
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(\sigma(wx_i)-y_i)^2,$$ and this is a binary classification problem over a single variable? 

Your reasoning over the quadratic and the asymptotics of the sigmoid function are correct.

Comment: It is indeed the empirical risk minimisation. 
We weren't told whether it's a binary classification over a single variable, but I assume it is (t.a tends to omit such information and we have to guess the hidden info).